# Totals with Cross Apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, cross-apply

I have 2 tables below and need get totals per each row from table 1 as new columns

> Table Programs:

```
AIR_DATE              START_TIME    END_TIME
-------------------------------------------
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   27000000    28800000
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   28800000    32400000
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   34200000    34280000
```

> Table Ratings:

```
IMPRESSION_DATE   IMP_START_TIME    IMP_END_TIME  HH    F2_5  IMP_STATUS
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   27000000    27899000      8685  4415   F
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   27900000    28799000      8690  4421   F 
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   28800000    29699000      9900  4410   F
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   29700000    30599000      9906  4414   F
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   30600000    31499000      6925  2580   F
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   31500000    32399000      6928  2588   F
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   32400000    33299000      9988  17     F
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   33300000    34199000      9998  19     F
1/26/2015 12:00:00 AM   34200000    35099000       781  2457   F
```

I am looking for how to get target result set as:

```
AIR_DATE    START_TIME  END_TIME  IMP_DATE IMP_START_TIME  IMP_END_TIME  HH_F  F2_5_F
1/26/2015   27000000    28800000  1/26/2015      27000000   28799000  8687.5   4418
1/26/2015   28800000    30600000  1/26/2015     28800000    30599000 8414.75   3498
1/26/2015   34200000    34280000  1/26/2015     34200000    35099000     781   2457
```

> My example of query, but It didn't help me:)

```
SELECT *
FROM PROGRAMS as P
    CROSS APPLY (
           SELECT 
              MIN(CASE WHEN R.IMP_STATUS = 'F' THEN IMP_START_TIME END) as IMP_START_TIME,
              MAX(CASE WHEN R.IMP_STATUS = 'F' THEN IMP_END_TIME END) as IMP_END_TIME,

              AVG(CASE WHEN R.IMP_STATUS = 'F' THEN HH END) as HH_F,
              AVG(CASE WHEN R.IMP_STATUS = 'F' THEN F2_5 END) as F2_5_F
            FROM RATINGS as R  
            WHERE R.IMPRESSION_DATE = P.AIR_DATE 
              AND R.IMP_START_TIME <= P.START_TIME 
              AND P.END_TIME <= R.IMP_END_TIME) as R
```

**RDBS**: MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2
**SQL Fiddler example here:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68fa5/2

Comment: Seems like you've incorrectly specified the boundaries in where condition in your query/ Please pay attention to AND R.IMP_START_TIME <= P.START_TIME, seems like it should be  AND R.IMP_START_TIME >= P.START_TIME

Comment: Updated the inital data. Thanks `jpw`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the time limiting condition in the cross apply to:

```
WHERE R.IMPRESSION_DATE = P.AIR_DATE 
  AND 
  (
    (R.IMP_START_TIME >= P.START_TIME AND R.IMP_END_TIME <= P.END_TIME) 
    OR
    (R.IMP_START_TIME <= P.START_TIME AND R.IMP_END_TIME >= P.END_TIME)
  )
```

you would get a result like:

```
AIR_DATE    START_TIME  END_TIME    IMP_START_TIME  IMP_END_TIME        HH_F    F2_5_F
2015-01-26 00:00:00.000 27000000    28800000    27000000    28799000    8687    4418
2015-01-26 00:00:00.000 28800000    32400000    28800000    32399000    8414    3498
2015-01-26 00:00:00.000 34200000    34280000    34200000    35099000    781     2457
```

which looks to be correct  :)

Comment: I could not create SQL Fiddler example, but my test is not passing with this answer

Comment: @SpanishBoy Oh, ok. Can you point out what is wrong with the result?

Comment: My bad it's really works - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aa0fb/1. Thanks! Does it possible to get another solution without using `CROSS APPLY`?

Comment: @SpanishBoy It should be possible as a cross join can be replaced with an inner join.

Comment: Looks like found the issue - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68fa5/2. Can you advise there?

Comment: @SpanishBoy I can't follow the logic of which rows that should be counted together to achieve the results. Could you clarify it in the question and maybe mark the rows in ratings somehow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82844/discussion-between-spanishboy-and-jpw).

Answer (score 0):

Which SQL Server version? Since 2008 you can use OVER with aggregate functions like MIN, MAX and AVG (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

EDIT: add exampel
Maybe you start off with a CTE and do the `SELECT MIN/MAX/AVG(x) OVER()` in the final SELECT?

```
WITH myCTE AS
(
    SELECT pr.AIR_DATE,pr.START_TIME,pr.END_TIME
    FROM Programs AS pr
    INNER JOIN Ratings AS rt ON pr.AIR_DATE =rt.IMPRESSION_DATE
                            AND pr.START_TIME=rt.IMP_START_TIME
                            AND pr.END_TIME <= rt.IMP_END_TIME 
)
SELECT * FROM myCTE
```